# Async Post with "await axios"

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios, nodemailer

in my React-App, I want to send an email with axios and nodemailer to the user after registration. So, when the button "Register" is pushed, it will use the api "/api/form" for sending the data to the server.
My problem is that the data will not be sent to the server in normal using. If I use the developertools with breackpoints for debugging this function, it works! So it can not be a problem with the server side, I think the problem is at the front end, but I don´t see why.
Is it the way I call axios.post?

Here is the code for the submit function (front end):

```js
async onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault
    var token = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);

    const { firstName, email, authToken } = this.state;

    const form = await axios.post('/api/form', {
       firstName,
       email,
       authToken: token
    }, console.log("form"),this.props.history.push(`/login`));
    return form;
  }
```

This is the code in index.js (server):

```js
/*Double-Opt-In*/
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

/*Double-Opt-In*/
app.post('/api/form', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
    token= req.body.authToken;
    link="http://localhost:3000/verify"+"?token="+token;
    console.log("createTestAccount");
    const htmlEmail = `
      <h3>WebFit Registrierung</h3>
    `

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        user: 'email',
        pass: 'password'
      }
    })

    let mailOptions = {
        from: 'WebFit', // sender address
        to: req.body.email, // list of receivers
        replyTo: 'app@webfit.app',
        subject: 'Welcome to Webfit <3', // Subject line
        text: req.body.message, // plain text body
        html: htmlEmail // html body
    };

    // send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
        // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
        console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

        // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>
        // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
    });
  });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
})
/*End Double-Opt-In*/
```

Comment: Do you see "form" log? Also, you don't need to log anything (or do the push logic) in the `axios.post` request. Since you are using async/await, you can log the response outside of the post request like it is synchronous.

Comment: Also, it is not `e.preventDefault`, it is `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: use Axios interceptor for the proper solution. else you will end up with cognitive dependencies in components.

Answer (score 0):

axios runs fine with async/await, so catch the throw/reject and check if axios or other. Depending on your api you can extract further info like shown:

```
async function login(token) {
  /* post token and return jwt */
  try {
    const d = await api.post("/login", token);
    return res.data["jwt"];
  } catch (e) {
    if(e.name == 'AxiosError'){
      // map axios error to an app-friendly display message
      // your api error handling dictates what you pull out, 
      //    expressjs: return res.status(401).send("expired.");
      //    results in: '401 expired.'
      return new Error(`${e.response.status} ${e.response.data}`);
    } else {
      return new Error(`${e.name} ${e.message}`);
    }
  }
}
```

If your tired of handling on every api call, use [interceptors](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors) which can do the api error 2 local app error mapping service.js wide.